# can you specify a thank you URL using stripe simple checkout form

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi I am trying to use stripe's simple checkout form on the leadpages.net platform (which means I can only use custom html and css)

Is there any way to specify a thank you URL in the parameters?

```
<form action="/create_subscription.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_live_xxxx"
    data-image="my.jpg"
    data-name="My form"
    data-description="30 Days for Free"
    data-amount="900"
    data-panel-label="Buy"
    data-label="Click here for instant access">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: in addition - is there any way to specify a product from my stripe account in this simple form setup?

Answer (score 0):

Originally this was not possible. Checkout only collected card details and gave you a card token (`tok_12345`) that you used server-side to create a charge or save the card on a Customer.

Stripe just released an update to Checkout in beta that would fit both your needs. You can see the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout). It will let you use a Product from your Dashboard and also define a redirect URL where customers are sent after having paid for the product.

Comment: Yes thank you! This is true - One qualification though. The generated code they give you is in javascript, so it unfortunately won't allow me to use it on this platform. That being said - Thank and great info. One other thing: You cannot run trial periods on subscriptions through this beta checkout yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet a way to do this using the only html / CSS and their simple checkout form. However as commented above, you can do this with their beta checkout using embedded javascript